# Target class [Admin\AdminController] does not exist

Tags: php, web, laravel-8

I'm developing a website using Laravel 8 by watching youtube tutorial, and I encounter an error message and don't know how to solve it. I tried to change the namespace but it didn't work.
[ERROR MESSAGE PICT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z8g9.png)

My AdminController.php code

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
   public function dashboard(){
       return view('admin.admin_dashboard');
   }
}
```

And my web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::prefix('/admin')-> namespace ('Admin')-> group (function(){
   //All the admin roles will be defined here
   Route::get('dashboard','AdminController@dashboard');
});
```

can anyone help me to solve this? thanks.

Comment: It's in the Admin folder, but it's already solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your namespace should be full path

```
Route::prefix('/admin')-> namespace ('Admin')-> group (function(){
  ...
});
```

Please change as below

```
Route::prefix('/admin')->namespace('App\\Http\\Controllers\\Admin')-> group (function(){
  ...
});
```

Comment: you may look into this https://dev.to/mr_steelze/laravel-8-routing-change-25co , there are few way to deal with new laravel 8 routing namespace

Comment: Hey I already corrected my code based on your instruction, and it works. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You have to include the whole path in namespace, like this...

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).